# How do I focus the current selection in a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html form with multiple questions that user need to answer, I want to add some style as : when the user clicks a question I want it to be focused and blur the other questions, how should I approach this.

Here is the form I made,but I wan to change the opacity of the div when clicked on the input field please suggest how to approach this.

```js
$(document).on('focus active', 'input, textarea', function(){
                    $('label[for='+$(this).attr('id')+']').addClass('active');
                });
                $(document).on('blur', 'input, textarea',function(){
                    $('label[for='+$(this).attr('id')+']').removeClass('active');
                });
```

```css
input[type=text], input[type="email"],input[type="number"] {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}
            input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
div {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.active{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: darkgray;
    opacity: 1 px !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <head>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
      </script>


         </head>
            <div>
                <label for="contact_form_name"><span class="qno">1.</span> What is your name?*</label>
                <input id="contact_form_name" name="contact_form_mail" type="text">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="contact_form_phone"><span class="qno">2.</span>What is your contact number?*</label>
                <input id="contact_form_phone" name="contact_form_phone" type="number">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="contact_form_email"><span class="qno">3.</span>What is your email address?**</label>
                <input id="contact_form_email" name="contact_form_email" type="email">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="contact_form_city"><span class="qno">4.</span>Which city do you live in?*</label>
                <input id="contact_form_city" name="contact_form_city" type="text">
            </div>
           
</body>
```

Comment: wow, you want us to write an entire application? only plain javascript or jquery/prototypejs/mootools allowed?

Comment: what you want to achieve something like other overlay

Answer (score 0):

You should have dedicated Id for each div(each question will be inside a div i suppose). Later use focus and blur events of javascript based on id

```
document.getElementById("your_id").blur();
document.getElementById("your_id").focus();
```

You can also populate an array containing id of those questions and iterate a loop to focus and blur

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would use JQuery to to add a class eg.focused on to the question the user is on, and all the other ones you would add another class eg.non-focused.

JQuery to add class to selected div

```
$(this).addClass('focused');
```

now in then add all the other div you add class non-focused

```
$('class_name_of_all_div').addClass('focused');
```

so you would have and html layout similar to this

```
<div class="question">
    <input type="text" name="name" >Name</input>
</div>
<div class="question">
    <input type="text" name="name" >Name</input>
</div
<div class="question">
    <input type="text" name="name" >Name</input>
</div
```

so your function would look like this

```
$(".question").click(function() {
     $(this).addClass('focused');
     $('.question').addClass('focused');
});
```

now you add the styling for it

```
.non-focused {
     filter: blur(2px);
}
```

and for focused

```
.non-focused {
     filter: blur(0px) !important;
}
```

and you should be set.

let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank-you I will try this and let you know.